# Why doesn't Promise catch error thrown by async operation?

Tags: javascript, error-handling, promise, es6-promise

Given the the following code:

```js
var fs = require('fs');

var asyncErrorPromise = new Promise(function(resolve) {
  fs.readFile('does/not/exist.blah', function(fileError, content) {
    if (fileError) throw fileError;
    resolve(content);
  });
});

asyncErrorPromise
  .then(function(content) {
    console.log('content received: ' + content);
  })
  .catch(function(err) {
    console.log('error received: ' + err.name);
  });
```

I would expect that the `fileError` that is thrown (because the file I try to load does not exist) will be caught by the Promise and funneled into the `.catch()` statement. So in the end I'd have this output: `error received: ENOENT`.

However, when I run this code I get the following instead:

```
    if (err) throw err;
             ^

Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'does/not/exist.blah'
    at Error (native)
```

So the error was not caught: it threw just as it normally would, as though it were outside a Promise.

Why is this happening?

Everything I can find to read about Promises is more concerned with errors being silently swallowed than with this problem, where it actually throws when you don't want it to!

And how *should* I achieve my intent here? Do I need to use try-catch statements and the `reject` handler?

Comment: As you mentioned you need to catch and reject/defer the promise. Any uncaught exception will be handled by the engine and will halt the script.

Comment: why would you `catch` the error? simply reject it

Comment: What promise lib are you using? In ES6, errors thrown inside a new promise constructor should implicitly reject the promise, so your code should work assuming the promise implementation is ES6 compat.

Comment: `errors thrown inside a new promise constructor should implicitly reject the promise` - node native ES6 promise doesn't seem to play well with others

Comment: Probably because the error is thrown inside of an async callback. If you throw outside of that as a test, it'll probably work. I'd follow the advice of the other commenters and simply reject the error.

Comment: @ehynds- you are correct

Comment: As a side note, one should never `throw` in custom async callback functions but instead reject the promise.

Comment: @DanielB: That's not really a side note: that's kind of the whole question. Is that a feature of Promises or a bug? Is the above *supposed* to happen? Why?

Comment: The behaviour **is** expected, and it's not a bug. Since it's async, you'll loose the context of the error in the `process.on('uncaughtException')` handler. To keep the context you'd have to use something like [Domain](https://nodejs.org/api/domain.html) where a `Domain` object handles the error in a handler.

Comment: That's the answer I was looking for, thanks! If you want to enter it as an answer instead of a comment I'll accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot catch an error thrown in an asynchronous callback function using promises, since its context will be lost. In your case with Node, you will loose the context of the error in the `process.on('uncaughtException')` handler, and the callback will run as its own event in the eventqueue, with its own context and scope.

Using promises, the correct solution will be to `reject` the wrapping promise.

An alternative would be to use a `Domain` object [(Domain documentation)](https://nodejs.org/api/domain.html), but it's pending deprecation. With a `domain` you can maintain the context and register a handler for your errors, as below.

```
var domain = require('domain');

var d = domain.create();

d.on('error', function(err){
    //Do something with your error
});

d.run(function(){
    //Run your async code that might throw error
});
```